# Could not find or load main class org.apache.nutch.tools.FileDumper

Tags: python, subprocess, cygwin, nutch

I am trying to issue an Apache Nutch command from a Python function, running on Windows and Cygwin via the `subprocess` module. However, while I can find nutch, I cannot seem to be running a Dump command to it.

This is an extract from my code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen(["c:/cygwin64/bin/bash.exe", '-c', 'C:/Users/.../nutch/runtime/local/bin/nutch dump -segment test/segments -outputDir outputDir -flatdir -mimetype audio/mpeg'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
print(p.communicate()[0])
```

However, running it returns the following:

```
b'c:/Users/.../nutch/runtime/local/bin/nutch: line 38: uname: command not found\nC:/Users/.../nutch/runtime/local/bin/nutch: line 110: dirname: command not found\nError: Could not find or load main class org.apache.nutch.tools.FileDumper\nCaused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.nutch.tools.FileDumper\r\n'
```

What am I missing exactly? Running the `dump` command from Cygwin proper (as opposed as Python) it works exactly as intended.

Comment: `uname` is a command available on `Cygwin`. If you are running outside Cygwin you need to properly set the PATH

Comment: Aah, that was it! Although there's a bit more to it, but it was mainly it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was simpler than I thought.
I just didn't have Cygwin64's folder in `PATH`, but other than that I also had to specify the *full path to the segments and output directories*

This code worked for me:

```
p = Popen(["c:/cygwin64/bin/bash.exe", '-c', '$NUTCH_HOME/bin/nutch dump -segment $NUTCH_HOME/test/segments -outputDir $NUTCH_HOME/outputDir -flatdir -mimetype audio/mpeg'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
```